# FreeBSD 10.0 upgrade network interface not working

Tags: networking, freebsd

FreeBSD noob here.

I have upgraded from FreeBSD 9.1-p11 to 10.0-RELEASE and am having problems with the network interface during boot.

It seems that something goes wrong with loading the driver or something similar. I can't find any specific messages in /var/log/messages.

I know that the network interface is a RealTek 8168/8111 B/C/CP/D/DP/E/F PCIe Gigabit Ethernet if that helps.

I'm looking for any pointers on how to procede with debugging/solving this problem.

Comment: Use your standard debugging tools: [ifconfig](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ifconfig%288%29), [dmesg](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dmesg&sektion=8), and [google](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=26726). Apparently there are two separate drivers for your NIC: the ones in the FreeBSD kernel, and the ones released by Realtek. Try one, then the other. If you don't know how to compile a driver from source then I can't help you.

Comment: ifconfig only tells me that the interface is not configured. I used dmesg to find the NIC make/model - anything else I could use it for? I have googled myself insane, but can't find anything.

Comment: The point of using dmesg/ifconfig is to see whether a driver is successfully initializing the device at all. Look for error messages or anything that may indicate a change in status for the device.